# i want to print date by the user in the format YYYY/MM/DD ,

Tags: bash

I want to print date by the user in the format `YYYY/MM/DD`, if user put that input like this way(`20042019`) which means `20/04/2019` that would be print like in this way `20/may/2019`.

Comment: Welcome to U&L, what efforts have you done to achieve your goal.

Comment: There weren't 2019 days in May in 20 - do you mean the format from the title, or from your example? Are you wanting to read and process the input too, or only format output?

Comment: I am suppose to run the script like this way " SH EXAMPLE.SH 20042019 " and then the output will be like this 20/Apr/2019 ,, btw i had mistake in the month counting from above question sorry about that !!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be a clear and coherent description of what you want to do.

Comment: It seems to me (guessing!) that you want to translate the user's input from YYYYMMDD (no slashes) into DD/lower-cased-month-name/YYYY. If I'm close, please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/516488/edit) to say it correctly. As-is, it's too easy to misinterpret "I want to print (the) date ... in the format YYYY/MM/DD", which is then confused against "be print(ed) in this way 20/may/2019".

Answer (score 1):

With **busybox** date (that supports the -D option), you can do:

```
$ busybox date -D '%d%m%Y' -d '20042019' +'%Y/%b/%d'
2019/Apr/20
```

Or, if you want full month names:

```
$ busybox date -D '%d%m%Y' -d '20042019' +'%Y/%B/%d'
2019/April/20
```

Note that the month name change when the language/country change.